# How does durability work?

Tags: the-secret-world

I just noticed the durability on my weapons is 290/300. I have a ways to go before they break on me, but I think it's worth figuring out the mechanics behind durability sooner rather than later.

How do items take damage? What happens when they run out of durability? What can I do to restore the durability of my items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The weapons degrade when you die, although this seems to be minor at this point in time. (I have taken quite a few deaths from unexpected blasts and my durability is about what you are seeing as well).

Since quite a bit of your effectiveness is based upon the gear this can be an issue. An example of this is seeing that the quests you are getting are being rated at Very Hard or Devastating. This can be because your gear is either out leveled or simply because your gear is damaged and thus less effective. From the information that I have found however (just found actually), the gear does not scale down its effectiveness. It will function the same when it is 300/300 or 5/300. Its when an item reaches 0 durability that it will stop working and thus why you see quests and such show such a difficult rating.

Fixing the items is fairly easy. Every merchant I have run into at this point in time has a Repair tab on them where you can see a list of your gear that needs repairing. You can then select the items in question or hit the Repair All button. It does cost a nominal fee to repair your gear but I have not seen anything over the top in this area, despite my fairly alarming deathrate.

Comment: Now if only I could find a vendor without having to travel back to New York every time I want to repair.

Comment: @StrixVaria In Kingsmouth just outside of the police station is an Apothecary. They can also repair your gear. If you are in the savage woods then there was also an Apothecary by the small center of town and another one in the school and such.

Comment: To this point I have never had to repair an item, as I've been able to replace it with an upgrade before it ever got to the point where it broke...